# Why won't my code access the ENTER or STRAIGHT folders or the .png files

Tags: python, image, pygame

i've written some code that takes images from folders and runs them in an animation but it can't open the folders or the images

I've tried putting the code in with the images too and it still wont open them

```py
def LoadAnimation(FOLDER, NAME, NUMBER):
    print(os.getcwd())
    ANIMATION = []
    for x in range(1,NUMBER):
        ANIMATION.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(FOLDER, (NAME + '-' + str(x) + '.png'))).convert())
    print(ANIMATION)
    return ANIMATION

def BasicQuest(NUMBER):
    print(os.getcwd())
    for counter in range(NUMBER):

        IMAGE = LoadAnimation('STRAIGHT','STRAIGHT',30)
        for x in range(29):
            IMAGE = pygame.transform.scale(IMAGE[x],(416,224))
            window.blit(IMAGE,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()

        IMAGE = LoadAnimation('ENTER','ENTER',30)
        for x in range(29):
            IMAGE = pygame.transform.scale(IMAGE[x],(416,224))
            window.blit(IMAGE,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()

    ANIMATION.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(FOLDER, (NAME + '-' + str(x) + '.png'))).convert())
```

Error message:

> pygame.error: Couldn't open STRAIGHT\STRAIGHT-1.png

Answer (score 0):

on your desktop, put your code in a special folder, and give the folder a name. Also put your images in the same folder, to make sure your python can find the images, because now he can't find them because you did't give the images a location. That should work.

Comment: Just tried that and it didnt work it still says that it can't open the image

Comment: maybe you have to use a / instead of \
pygame.error: STRAIGHT/STRAIGHT-1.png

Comment: or just don't use this: 
(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(FOLDER, (NAME + '-' + str(x) + '.png'))).convert()) 

and replace it for pygame.image.load(STRAIGHT)